# Center of a circle and shopping center

Tags: word-usage

There is a disagreement in the office. Are 'center of a circle' and 'shopping center' using the same meaning of the word *center*? Don't they both mean the middle or heart of the thing being referenced?

Comment: Yes, they are (more formally all the senses you mention are in the same semantic field, all related to the fundamental metaphor of "center"). What do your opponents say?

Comment: this is my position. They say they have independent meanings.

Comment: You can physically go to the center of a shopping center because shopping center refers to a location at which shopping can be performed. [It even has it's own definition.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/shopping-center)

Comment: Not all shopping centers  are in the middle of town. There are plenty to be found on the outskirts of cities.

Answer (score 5):

They're two different meanings for the same word.  From the Oxford Dictionary (which has "centre" rather than "center" but we can ignore that distinction, I think):

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/centre

> 1: The point that is equally distant from every point on the circumference of a circle or sphere.
>
> 2: The point from which an activity or process is directed, or on which it is focused

It doesn't make sense to say that a shopping centre is at the "middle" of the shopping - if anything, it's the other way round:  the shopping is contained **within** the "shopping centre".

Comment: but isn't the shopping center the point around which the shopping revolves? in reference to the first answer.

Comment: In my experience a shopping centre is a large building (like a mall) or area **containing** many shops, rather than a point which is in the middle of all the shops.

Comment: If you compare _shopping center_ or _garden center_ with _town center_ or _city center_, you'll see that the two _centers_ have indeed a different meaning. Of course, the two meanings are related and (obviously) share an etymological background, but they are semantically different in modern usage.

Answer (score 2):

Center of a ***[circle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=center)*** is the original meaning, ***by extension*** "the middle of anything" that is of the shopping in your specific case:

> - late 14c., "middle point of a circle; point round which something revolves," from Old French centre (14c.), from Latin centrum "center," ***originally fixed point of the two points of a drafting compass***, from Greek kentron "sharp point, goad, sting of a wasp," from kentein "stitch," from PIE root *kent- "to prick" (source also of Breton kentr "a spur," Welsh cethr "nail," Old High German hantag "sharp, pointed").
> - ***Figuratively from 1680s. Meaning "the middle of anything" attested from 1590s.*** Spelling with -re popularized in Britain by Johnson's dictionary (following Bailey's), though -er is older and was used by Shakespeare, Milton, and Pope. Center of gravity is recorded from 1650s. Center of attention is from 1868.

(Etymonline)

Comment: A center is defined as `a place or group of buildings where a specified activity is concentrated.` in the oxford dictionary, so I'd say they were two separate definitions even though one implies the other. If you were to say City Center however, I'd argue it could be the same definition.

Comment: @SLC - as I said, "by extension" of the original meaning.

Comment: Yes, I didn't feel it answered the original question though.

Comment: if shopping center references center by extension, I would argue they are fundamentally the same meaning

Comment: @user53949 -        Yes, terms have  semantic changes and extentions during the centuries. The idea is the same, appiled to place with a central point around which activites take place (in this case shopping)